# Convert json string containing utf-8 symbols to a php array

Tags: php, utf-8, json

I'm trying to convert a json string containing  utf-8 symbols to a php array.

```php
$jsonString = '{"loginid" : "90", "username" : "\U0437\U0430\U043c\U043a\U0435"}';

$array = json_decode($jsonString,true);
```

Unfortunately `json_decode` returns null.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. http://jsonlint.com Where is that coming from?

Comment: it's not even valid PHP either. `$jsonString` and `$array`, perhaps?

Comment: @deceze you are totally right... did not notice the missing \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\u` instead of `\U`. Try this:

```
$jsonString = '{"loginid" : "90", "username" : "\u0437\u0430\u043c\u043a\u0435"}';

$array = json_decode($jsonString,true);
```

Comment: yeah i kind of rushed to post without reviewing what i was typing. fixed that. You are also right in your suggestion thet the u should be  lowercase. As I commented in the first answer the Web Service I'Am getting this from is not delivering correct json.

Comment: I see. You just have to filter it first: `$jsonString =  preg_replace('/\\\U/','\u', $jsonString);`

Comment: Yep this is the way to go. was about to reply that. it is more of a hack though. better fix this on the web service side. ty for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping your slashes.

```
<?php

$jsonString = '{"loginid" : "90", "username" : "\\\U0430"}';

$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);

print "<PRE><FONT COLOR=ORANGE>"; print_r($array); print "</FONT></PRE>";
```

Comment: Yeah kind of to obvious... d'oh. So the WebService providing this is buggy. TY

Comment: bprayudha was right with the lowercase u. anyway thx for your help :)